# gwt-openlayers with openstreetmap example

Tags: gwt, openstreetmap, gwt-openlayers

I'd like to integrate OSM in GWT.
I found this library called gwt-openlayers, but I don't understand how can I make it work with  the OSM map.

Can anyone provide me a short example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you inherit from gwt-openlayers by adding the following to your module file:

`<inherits name='org.gwtopenmaps.openlayers.OpenLayers'/>`

Also make sure you bring in the OpenLayers javascript library and OpenStreetMap OpenLayers into your application by adding the following lines in "Application.html" page:

`<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>`

`<script src="http://www.openstreetmap.org/openlayers/OpenStreetMap.js"></script>`

Then it should a simple thing to create a layer that uses open street maps:

`OSM openStreetMap = OSM.Osmarender("Base Map");`
`openStreetMap.setIsBaseLayer(true);`

`MapWidget mapWidget = new MapWidget("350px", "350px");`
`mapWidget.getMap().addLayer(openStreetMap);`

Comment: Is there a safe CDN for OpenLayers.js and OpenStreetMap.js?

Answer (score 11):

**GWT-OpenLayers`HelloWorld`with OpenStreetMap**

The following example works fine for me using`OpenLayers-2.8/OpenLayers.js`and`OpenStreetMap.js`as described above:

> public void onModuleLoad() {
>
> ```
> MapOptions defaultMapOptions = new MapOptions();
> MapWidget mapWidget = new MapWidget("800px", "600px", defaultMapOptions);
>
> OSM osm_1 = OSM.Osmarender("Osmarender");   // Label for menu 'LayerSwitcher'
>     osm_1.setIsBaseLayer(true);
>
> OSM osm_2 = OSM.Mapnik("Mapnik");   // Label for menu 'LayerSwitcher'
>     osm_2.setIsBaseLayer(true);
>
> OSM osm_3 = OSM.CycleMap("CycleMap"); 
>     osm_3.setIsBaseLayer(true);
>
> OSM osm_4 = OSM.Maplint("Maplint"); 
>     osm_4.setIsBaseLayer(true);
>
> Map map = mapWidget.getMap();
>     map.addLayer(osm_1);
>     map.addLayer(osm_2);
>     map.addLayer(osm_3);
>     map.addLayer(osm_4);
>     map.addControl(new LayerSwitcher());
>     map.addControl(new MousePosition());
>
>  // map.setCenter(new LonLat(6.95, 50.94), 12);            // Warning:  In the case of OSM-Layers the method 'setCenter()' uses Gauss-Krueger coordinates,
>                                                            //           thus we have to transform normal latitude/longitude values into this projection first:
>     LonLat lonLat = new LonLat(6.95, 50.94);               //           (6.95, 50.94)  -->  (773670.4, 6610687.2)
>            lonLat.transform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:900913");   //           
>     map.setCenter(lonLat, 12);                             //           see  http://docs.openlayers.org/library/spherical_mercator.html
>
> RootPanel.get().add(mapWidget); }
> ```

Comment: The `defaultMapOptions` and the `map.setCenter(lonLat, 12);` part seems to be very important...

Answer (score 1):

you find the current version of gwt-openlayers here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gwt-openlayers/